# SQLite: ResultSet cursor already at the end after stmt.executeQuery()

Tags: sqlite, cursor, resultset

I'm reading from an SQLite Database into a ResultSet with the command `allCustomers = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customers");`

The table `customers` has 3 columns: `customerID`, `firstname`, `lastname`
at which the customerID is an integer from 0 to 199.

After doing some other stuff in my code I come to the line:

```
if(alleKunden.next()){
    System.out.println( allCustomers.getInt(1) + " " + allCustomers.getString(2));
}
```

In this line I get an `column 2 out of bounds [1,1]`Error. If I drop 
`allCustomers.getString(2)` the output will be `200` and at the next iteration (as this happens in a for loop) the exception `ResultSet closed`terminates the program.

I checked the database with the firefox plugin SQLite and found out that the database correctly contains all customer information.

So why is there no second column in my ResultSet and why do I get "200" as a result of allCustomers.getInt(1)

Here is my entire code:
(Note: For some reasons the exact same thing works fine in the first task `createCustomers()`)

```
package telefonbook;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

class SqlDB {

    private static final SqlDB dbcontroller = new SqlDB(Application.VERBOSE_MODE, Application.CREATE_NEW_DATA, Application.FAKTOR, Application.DB_PATH);
    private static Connection connection;
    private static final String DB_PATH = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/" + "tmp/telefonbook.sqlite";

    static boolean verboseMode;
    static boolean createNewData;
    static int faktor;
    static String dbPath;

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Error with the JDBC driver");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public SqlDB(boolean verboseMode, boolean createNewData, int faktor, String dbPath){
        this.verboseMode = verboseMode;
        this.createNewData = createNewData;
        this.faktor = faktor;
        this.dbPath = dbPath;
    }

    public static SqlDB getInstance(){
        return dbcontroller;
    }

    private void initDBConnection() {
        try {
            if (connection != null)
                return;
            System.out.println("Creating Connection to Database...");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + DB_PATH);
            if (!connection.isClosed())
                System.out.println("...Connection established");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (!connection.isClosed() && connection != null) {
                        connection.close();
                        if (connection.isClosed())
                            System.out.println("Connection to Database closed");
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void createCustomers(int customerAmount) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Creating customers...\n ");

            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer;");
            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE customer (customerID, lastname, firstname);");
            String  firstname;
            String lastname;

            for (int i = 0; i < customerAmount; i++){
                    //here a random name is generated. Gonna skip this code
                    firstname = randomname();
                    lastname = randomname();

                    stmt.execute("INSERT INTO customer (customerID, lastname, firstname) VALUES (" + i + ",'" + lastname + "','" + firstname + "')");
            }
            connection.commit();
            if(verboseMode){
                ResultSet allCustomers = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customer");
                while(allCustomers.next()){
                    System.out.println(allCustomers.getString(1) + "\t" + allCustomers.getString(2) + "\t" +allCustomers.getString(3));
                }
            }   
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't handle DB-Query");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void createTelefone(int telefonAmount) {
        try {
            String  telefonnumber;
            System.out.print("Creating telefones...\n ");
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS telefone;");
            stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE telefone (telefonID, telefonnumber, ownerID);"); 
            ResultSet allCustomers = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customer");
            int customerAmount = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer").getInt(1);

            for (int i = 0; i < telefonAmount; i++){
                telefonnumber = randomNumber();
                if(allCustomers.next()){
                    // This line will fail!
                    System.out.println(allCustomers.getInt(1) + " " + allCustomers.getString(2));
                    stmt.execute("INSERT INTO telefone (telefonID, telefonnumber, ownerID) VALUES (" + i + ",'" + telefonnumber + "', " + allCustomers.getInt(1) + ")");
                } else {
                    //do something else
                }
            }
            ResultSet allTelefones = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM telefone");
            if(verboseMode){
                while(allTelefones.next()){
                    System.out.println(allTelefones.getString(1) + "\t" + allTelefones.getString(2) + "\t" +allTelefones.getString(3));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't handle DB-Query");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public static void Application() {
        int customerAmount = 100*faktor;
        int telefonAmount = 100*faktor;

        SqlDB dbc = SqlDB.getInstance();
        dbc.initDBConnection();
        try{
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            if (createNewData){
                dbc.createCustomers(customerAmount);
                dbc.createTelefone(telefonAmount);
            }
        connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I didn't found the source of the problem but figured out a workaround.

First of all I had (for some reasons I couldn't figure out) to uncomment the following line.

```
int customerAmount = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer").getInt(1);
```

After that I replaced the `stmt.execute` in line:

```
stmt.execute("INSERT INTO telefone (telefonID, telefonnumber, ownerID) VALUES (" + i + ",'" + telefonnumber + "', " + allCustomers.getInt(1) + ")");
```

with a `java.sql.PreparedStatement` in the following way:

```
PreparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO telefone VALUES(?,?,?);");
prep.setInt(1, i); // telefonID
prep.setString(2, telefonnumber); // telefonnumber
prep.setInt(3, randomOwner); // ownerID
prep.addBatch();
```